# Example of a parsing/rewriting system?

Tags: formal-languages, parsers, term-rewriting

I am studying formal languages and playing with writing my own parsers for them. I have a context free grammar parser already that works well. I am wondering if anyone can point me towards actually implemented examples of rewriters. For example, suppose I had the rules

WORD: [A-Z]+

QUOTE: "

And I wanted to input a lot of words,put quotes around each one, and write out the string. Or go back and forth. Something like this:

(WORD [' '])+   <--> (QUOTE WORD QUOTE [' '])+

That seems kind of possible to implement automatically without ambiguity, but I was hoping someone had seen something along that line that already exists.

Comment: Stratego is a system that allows you to write term-rewrite rules and it will compile them for you.

Comment: A link: http://strategoxt.org/

Comment: Hi @Dave. I read up on it and it's pretty complex. Do you use it for anything? Can you describe the syntax for the above example?

Comment: I haven't used it for years, unfortunately. I always mean to, but never find the time.

Comment: For actual example using ANTLR see [Example tree rewriting with patterns](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/~admin/2008/11/30/Example+tree+rewriting+with+patterns)

Answer (score 3):

[Thue](http://catseye.tc/projects/thue/) language is based on string rewriting and it's just 179 lines of c code.

[Pure](https://code.google.com/p/pure-lang/) is an LGPL'd functional language based on term rewriting.

Not an example, but a [course](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~tcs/trs/) with really complete slides on the theory of term rewriting systems.

Answer (score 0):

My [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is an example of a system based on rewriting terms (ASTs produced by parsing), used to carry out massive code transformations.  You can [see a description of its rewrite rules](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a relatively simple [bottom-up parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing) using a [string rewriting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Thue_system) in Prolog. In this example, the input is `[a,plus,b,plus,sum,of,c,and,d]` and the output is `[[[a,+,b],+,c],+,d]`:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag('double_quotes','chars').

main :-
    rewrite_system([a,plus,b,plus,sum,of,c,and,d],X),writeln(X).

% this predicate is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312742/975097
replace(ToReplace, ToInsert, List, Result) :-
    once(append([Left, ToReplace, Right], List)),
    append([Left, ToInsert, Right], Result).

rewrite_system(Input,Output) :-
    is_terminal(Input),Input=Output;
    rewrite_rule(A,B),
    replace(A,B,Input,Input1),
    writeln(Input1),
    rewrite_system(Input1,Output).

rewrite_rule([sum,of,A,and,B],[A,plus,B]).
rewrite_rule([A,plus,B],[A,+,B]).
rewrite_rule([A,+,B],[[A,+,B]]).
is_terminal([A,+,B]).
```

Using the same principle, I wrote [an adaptive parser](https://github.com/jarble/adaptive_parser) that "learns" new grammar rules from its input.